# (ReactJS) I have mapping of account numbers with balances how to display it as a table in react?

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I have a mapping with key being account number and value being account balance:

```
"balance": {
1: 1000,
2: 2000,
3: 3000
}
```

How do I display this content as a table in react?

| account | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 3000 |

Comment: Can you please show how you would like the result to look like?

Comment: just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on here, for what exactly what you want, but I think ultimately you would do something like this in your render function.

```js
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>account</th>
    <th>balance</th>
  </tr>
  {Object.keys(balance).map((x) => (
    <tr key={x}>
      <td>{x}</td>
      <td>{balance[x]}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

I just freehanded this, so probably can't copy-paste, but going off the information provided, I would think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: i just editted my question that includes what the table should look like

Comment: Updated my response above to include the headers and other column.